# FileLoadException on project references when running tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I have some test projects that have reference to dlls that are constantly being uptade by a server who build them. So far so good. But sometimes when I run the tests, the test Project tries to load the previous version of referenced dll.

Ex: The referenced dll is in 6.5.0.381 version, but my test Project looks for the 6.5.0.380 version, raising the following exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly “myassembly, Version=6.5.0.380”

Checking the properties of the reference, the build of the reference is in the correct version (6.5.0.381 - the new version).

Is there any other location where the Project keeps the version of referenced dlls?